# C# MD5 hash to Groovy MD5 hash

Tags: c#, grails, encryption, groovy

I need to make a MD5 hash in Groovy (Grails) that gives the exact same result as the one I have in C#

The C# code use MD5 function

`tmpHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(tmpIn);`

what function is there in groovy that I can use?

I tried

`licenseKeys = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(tempAr).encodeHex()`

But that gives me almost same result, some times it has extra zeros in different locations, the rest of the code is not important as its just making string into byte and i know MD5 is old and unsecured but still has to use it

When input is *AAAAAAAA* the c# output is
*87D746DB2DB357978BC97C92123622*
and in groovy
*87D746DB2D0B357978BC970C92123622*

But with input as *AAAAA* its the same
*C94EE213E7FA6887256D143E924227C4*

to get the tempAr in groovy I do this

```
byte[] array = temp.getBytes("UTF-8")  
byte[] tempAr = new byte[array.size() * 2]  

// to add 0 after each byte  
for (int i = 0; i < tempAr.size(); i++){  
    if (!(i%2)){     
        tempAr[i] = array[((int)(i * 0.5))]  
    }  
    else{  
        tempAr[i] = 0  
    }  
}
```

I do this becuse the old c# code does it as well, I know its weird...

the c# code to get the byte is

```
tmpIn = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(txtFirstname.Text + txtLastname.Text);
```

Comment: Extra zeroes where?  Do you have an example?  And what you expected?  And how do you define "sometimes"?

Comment: In general the first error is: "make a **MD5** hash", while for some usages MD5 is acceptable in general it is time to move up to at least SHA-256.

Comment: When I am using a standard function and get strange and/or incorrect results my first thought is "I'm doing it wrong"™. Please provide a [MCVE] and that includes input and output data.

Comment: How are you making `tempArr`, also with `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest('AAAAAAAA'.bytes).encodeHex().toString()` I get `aee9e38cb4d40ec2794542567539b4c8` not `87D746DB2DB357978BC97C92123622` as you . put in your question...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the the C# version is not displaying the "0" characters. The result should be 16 bytes displayed as 32 characters in hex, C# result is short.

```
87D746DB2D B357978BC97 C92123622 C#
87D746DB2D0B357978BC970C92123622 groovy
```

There is a error in the display code.

> Note:
>
> ```
> C94EE213E7FA6887256D143E924227C4
> ```
>
> is the same because there are no "0" characters in either C# or groovy display.

Comment: But when I input _aaaa_
the output is the same and it has "0" characters in it
_86D062828C1DBCE2A48D93742BD3F8E_

Comment: @Faunus The is a error in the C# display code, grasshopper. The difference is wether the "0" is on the most significant of least significant byte. `0B` vs `D0`. Guess: in the C# formatting code leading `0` characters are not specified. Add the C# hex formatting code, not the groovy code.